# Reduce the rate of dropped packets in ns2

Tags: udp, ns2, packet-loss

I have made an ad hoc simulation with 7 nodes. I use udp agents in the 2 nodes who are both transmitters and receivers cause I am simulating a video conference.The other 4 nodes are in between and move slightly.

My problem is that no matter the protocol (dsdv, aodv, dsr), the simulation time or the packet size I use, my packet lose is huge for both nodes, usually over 87%.

What should I try?

Comment: ? Multicast. .. .. Examples https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNa0pKc0V2UEdDWTQ/view?usp=sharing ... All ~2500 examples https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7S255p3kFXNSmRYb2lGcDRUdWs?usp=sharing

Comment: »» Reduce the rate of dropped packets in ns2 «« : Dropped packets usually means "delivered (dropped) OK at destination (drop point)". AFAIK.

Comment: hi thanks for the examples you sent me! i will look at them and i hope they help me! yes the problem is that the rate of the dropped packets is always over 87% ! no i have read that dropped packets are these which dont arrive at destination and delivered packets are these which arrive! delivered+dropped are all the packets generated.